# Xdebug Configuration - Random Whitespace after IP

Tags: php, variables, xdebug

I am fighting an Xdebug issue:
For some reason a whitespace gets added behind the IP address when I am using my env. variable.

This is what my Xdebug config looks like:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=${PUBLIC_HOST_IP}
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

Within my browser php info file it looks fine:

[image]

But within my debug log it shows me:

`WARN: Creating socket for '10.44.9.72 :9003', getaddrinfo: Invalid argument.`

When I add the IP directly to the configuration, Xdebug is working fine, so the issue coming from the usage of the environmental variable.
I also already send it through a replacement:

```
PUBLIC_HOST_IP=$(hostname -I)
export PUBLIC_HOST_IP=$(echo "${PUBLIC_HOST_IP}" | tr -d '[:space:]')
```

But without any luck for now ...

When I add a "1" behind my configuration, the whitespace also appears in the info php.

```
xdebug.client_host=${PUBLIC_HOST_IP}1
```

[image]

Also wrapping didnt help: `xdebug.client_host="${PUBLIC_HOST_IP}"`

When I write the variable to a text file:

`echo $PUBLIC_HOST_IP >> test.txt`

No whitespace is added to the end of the ip.
Any clue how to get rid of that whitespace?

Comment: What is generating the xdebug config, or more specifically, what is transforming the environment variable? (I'm not familiar with using variables in there so if it is possible that is new to me.) Is this Docker?

Comment: The normal env. variables can simply be used within php configuration files:
https://www.php.net/manual/de/configuration.file.php

Comment: I did not know that! I'm not helping you, unfortunately, but I'm learning something at least!

Comment: In your code, can you call `getenv` on that and parse it out as bytes. I'm just wondering if there's a Unicode-like whitespace at the end that is messing with you.

Comment: Are you sure it's not a new line, instead of a space? What happens if you do `xdebug_var_dump(ini_set('xdebug.client_host'));` ?

Comment: Why should is run ini_set() within xdebug_var_dump() ... ?

`ini_set() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given`

Comment: @Basti Must be a typo. I bet Derick meant to write `ini_get` instead (which makes more sense here/based on what needs to be checked).

Comment: That indeed makes way more sense :-)
What i get is: `string(10) "10.44.9.72"`

Answer (score 0):

I have no damn clue why, but changing my config file from:

```
zend_extension=xdebug
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.start_with_request=yes
xdebug.client_host=${PUBLIC_HOST_IP}
xdebug.log=/tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey=VSCODE
```

To

```
zend_extension = xdebug
xdebug.mode = debug
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.client_host = ${PUBLIC_HOST_IP}
xdebug.log = /tmp/xdebug.log
xdebug.idekey = VSCODE
```

Actually fixed it ...

Comment: That... makes no sense :-) Is the problem there if you revert it back to the old style?

Comment: @Derick: Yes i did and the whitespace reoccured ... I will just take that :-)

Comment: I'm wondering whether this is a bug in PHP perhaps then. Which version are you running? FWIW, I can't reproduce this at all.